# Python Dict Transform

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been having some strange difficulty trying to transform a dataset that I have.

I currently have a dictionary coming from a form as follows:

```
data['content']['answers']
```

I would like to have the ['answers'] appended to the first element of a list like so:

```
data['content'][0]['answers']
```

However when I try to create it as so, I get an empty dataset.

```
data['content'] = [data['content']['answers']]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: Here is the opening JSON

I have:

```
{
"content" : {
              "answers" : {
                "3" : {
```

But I need it to be:

```
    {
"content" : [
              {
                 "answers" : {
                  "3" : {
```

thanks

Comment: Show us a repeatable example

Comment: You have a dict-of-dict, and you say you want to convert it to a dict-of-list-of-dict

Comment: yes exactly, I've added some more info

Comment: Wouldn't `d = {k:[v] for k,v in d.items()}` work? In your edit you are just putting brackets around the values of the outer dictionary.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Please post an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: In Python, sometimes the answer is too short to see. It almost seems like cheating how short an answer might be. In any event, I posted it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want by using a *dictionary comprehension* (which is one of the most elegant and powerful features in Python.)

In your case, the following should work:

```
d = {k:[v] for k,v in d.items()}
```

You mentioned JSON in your question. Rather than rolling your own parser (which it seems like you *might* be trying to do), consider using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood the question correctly, it sounds like you need `data['contents']` to be equal to a list where each element is a dictionary that was previously contained in `data['contents']`?

I believe this might work (works in Python 2.7 and 3.6):

```
# assuming that data['content'] is equal to {'answers': {'3':'stuff'}}

data['content'] = [{key:contents} for key,contents in data['content'].items()]

>>> [{'answers': {'3': 'stuff'}}]
```

The list comprehension will preserve the dictionary content for each dictionary that was in `contents` originally and will return the dictionaries as a list.

Python 2 doc: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Python 3 doc:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you give us a concrete example of 'data' (what the dictionary looks like), what code you try to run, what result you get and what you except. I think I have an idea but can't be sure.

Comment: Just added more info above.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. Please don't post comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear and lacks of an explicit example.

Btw, something like this can work for you?

```
data_list = list()
for content in data.keys():
    data_list.append(data[content])
```